# Lista dinámicas de dos columnas en flutter

Tags: json, bucle-for, flutter, bucles, vscode

La idea es tener un `listView` debido a que son muchas repeticiones
y dentro del `listView` tener una `row` que contiene dos contenedores (Container) o Expanded,

En mi caso yo use un json que tenia la siguiente estructura y se repetía mientras mas objetos coloque en ese arreglo llamado myApp

```json
"myApp": [

        {
            "titulo":"Lorem Ipsum",
            "subtitulo":"lorem..."            
        },
        {
            "titulo":"Lorem Ipsum",
            "subtitulo":"lorem..."
        },

    ]
```

Dentro de los contenedores que están en la fila colocaría esos títulos y subtítulos

[image]

Comment: Usa GridView ;)

Comment: @diegoveloper gracias, aunque ya lo solucione un ciclo for... ahora tengo el proble de que coloque ese listView dentro de un TaBar, solo tiene dos tabs pero cada tabs contiene el mismo listView, el problema esque cuando desliza se vuelven a llamar ese ciclo cada vez que se pasa de una pestaña a otra... :(